# CSS width should depend on parent

Tags: css, html

I guess this is a standard css problem, but I can't figure it out.

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer">
        <img class="img">
        <div>
            <h4><a href="#">Link</a></h4>
            <span>Text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <img class="img">
        <div>
            <h4><a href="#">Link</a></h4>
            <span>Longer Text which breaks the design</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <img class="img">
        <div>
            <h4><a href="#">Link</a></h4>
            <span>Text</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.container {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.outer {
    width: 31%;
    margin: 0.5em;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
}

.outer div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.img {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a6ZjS/

As you can see, if the text inside the `<span>` element gets to long the design breaks. But I would like the text to break and not the design. There may also be some unnecessary stuff in the css.

Comment: You have to set a maximum width on the red divs

Comment: The problem is I don't know the exact width, it's 31% - 80px - 30px margin. If this isn't possible with css, maybe it helps to know I use SASS.

Comment: You really can know it because is 31% of 800px your main container so do the maths

Comment: I know I can calculate 31% from 800px, but the entire thing uses media queries and the width is dependent on the device resolution.

Comment: You can with `calc` check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of solving it:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/a6ZjS/19/

```
.outer {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.outer div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the max width of the spans so that they wouldn't exceed their parent (ex: `max-width: 133px;`).

http://jsfiddle.net/a6ZjS/6/.

Also, with long texts in that example, the margins on the `h4` tags would push the second row of text out of the box. I just set it to `margin: 0px;` to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a max for width and height should do the trick. Also putting overflow: auto will let it scroll if the div gets too big.

```
.outer div {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
   background-color: red;
   overflow: auto;
   max-width: 130px;
   max-height: 80px;
}
```

See the code in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/a6ZjS/10/

Answer (score 0):

Padding percentage relative to its element's width

```
.content{
     paddding: 30%
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.